# Redirecting to a separate Django view after Ajax request is successful

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Django/Python server-side dev here. And also a JS newbie (8 days old). This question is about Ajax-initiated page reloads.

Here's a JS snippet where I'm processing the JSONResponse from a Django view I POSTed some data to. Depending on success or failure, you'll see that I'm calling a redirect to another Django view:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
       {
            var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            if (!resp.success) {
                console.log("Failed!");
            } else {
                console.log("Success! Redirect to: ", resp.success_url);
                window.location.href = resp.success_url;
                window.location.reload();
            }
       }
    }; 
  xhr.open('POST', e.target.action);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", get_cookie('csrftoken'));
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
  xhr.send(form_data);
```

Specifically, the following lines do the trick:

```
window.location.href = resp.success_url;
window.location.reload();
```

My problem is that when this gets executed in Firefox, I am made to see the following dialog box:

[image]

It seems the `POST` parameters are being sent again ?! How do I just do a plain old `GET` type redirect to `resp.success_url` instead? Please advise and let me know if you need more information.

*Note: let's stick to pure JS for the scope of this question - I'm learning vanilla JS these days and don't want to get into JQuery prematurely.*

Comment: what is your `resp.success_url`?

Comment: That's because you reload it. That's window.location.href = resp.success_url; enought

Comment: @AmitJoki: it's a relative url. E.g. `/home/`

Comment: @Denis: I didn't get that right. You mean I should exclude `window.location.reload();` from the code? Or something else? Please clarify.

Comment: @HassanBaig the reason I asked is, whether that url is same as that of the current url

Comment: @AmitJoki: no, it's not the same, the current one is, for instance, `/pcp/` where the paramteres were POSTed to.

Comment: @Denis: that worked, but so does `window.location.replace(resp.success_url);`. Any idea what's the qualitative difference between the two approaches (e.g. differences in efficiency, browser compatibility, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
window.location.replace(resp.success_url);
```

Comment: This works, and so does using `window.location.href = resp.success_url;` solely. Any idea what's the qualitative difference between the two approaches (e.g. differences in efficiency, browser compatibility, etc)?

Comment: They're pretty much the same i think, except that the `replace` method navigates to the URL without adding a new record to the history.